# MSSQL/PHP to HighChart via JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json, highcharts

Im trying to get data from my SQL server via php, and output it as JSON, so i can use it for HighCharts. So far i can get it to post my results as different series if that makes any sense.

SQL/PHP:

```
$params = array(&$_POST['query']);

$tsql1 = "SELECT TOP 10 Company_Names, Revenue_Value1, Revenue_Value2

FROM Database.test report
GROUP BY Company_Name 
ORDER BY Revenue_Value1

$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);

$getProducts = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql1, $params, $options);

if ($getProducts === false)

die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) );



while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $getProducts );?>
```

the sql prints out something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNS3q.png

And prints this chart:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kdaf.png

Obviously, this is not how i want it to output..

I want it to output xAxis as Quarters, yAxis as Revenue_Value1 and Series-name as Company_Name.

i am currently using this to get my php data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Revenue',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
                    title: { text: 'Months'}
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Revenue'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: json
            });
        });

    });

});
        </script>
```

---

data.php echoes:

```
{"Company_Names":"Company_Name","Revenue_Value1":45443,"Revenue_Value2":4654}
```

Of course i had to change some values because of some rules.. i hope that you can still see what i am trying to achieve.

EDIT:

```
    $arr = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
    $name = $row['Distributor'];
    $data = array($row['Value']);

    $arr[] = array('name' => $name, 'data' => $data);
}

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This put my data out a way that HighCharts could read it

Comment: You have a sintax error, missing `";` after `ORDER BY Revenue_Value1`

Comment: Are you getting some error ?

Comment: As for the sql.. I was just trying to paint a picture of what my data would look like, so it's not really the sql I use, but an example of what it looks like. 

I got the Json data working with the right data formatted the right way. I will post an edit to it soon, with the php lines I used. My problem besides the wrong php code, was that I were filtering on some wrong tables, which only gave me some data for one particular period of time, instead of giving me 12 months of data that I could plot in. 

But as I've said, I will post the answer as soon as I get to my laptop :-)

Comment: Please take look at preprocessing article http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing which should be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your series should be in an array try something var `j =[]; j.push(json);` then do `series: j`

Comment: What i did was:

$arr = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
 $name = $row['ResellerName'];
    $data = array($row['COGS']);

    $arr[] = array('name' => $name, 'data' => $data);
}

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: How your data looks like when you get it by ajax / js ? not how it is displayed in php.

Comment: What does the JSON looks like?

Comment: [{"name":"xx","data":[yy]},{"name":"xx1","data":[yy1]},{"name":"xx2","data":[yy2]},{"name":"xx3","data":[yy3]},{"name":"xx4","data":[yy4]}]

Comment: This is what im left with. http://i.imgur.com/2bNvGsf.png- i want it to show 5 different names with 5 different values